# How to extract a number (float) from a specific line of a file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input, line

I am a C++ beginner and trying to create a program that keeps track of the products each waiter serves in a bar. Part of it is reading prices from a text file.

Each line is the price of one specific product.

The user is supposed to type the products "code" which practically is the line of the product that has been served (all this will be in a loop because many products will be served).

When the user types a number, let's say 5, how can i get the price out of the 5th line of the text?

Maybe there is a way to import the file into an array when the program starts but i don't know how to do that.

UPDATE:
I finally fixed the code errors, but I am really unhappy with my program. Even I, when it asks Y/N for special price, I just input the special price and it interprets is as "NO". Also, I now want it to keep track of sum of money each waiter has earned, and each waiter has a name in a text file similar to the others (e.g first waiter's name is in the first line of waiters.txt and goes on....) but there will only be 4-5 waiters depending on the day. How can I expand the program without having to start from scratch?

I solved it myself. To get the lines from the file use this

```
char product_names[101][15];
fstream file("prices.txt");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
         file >> product_prices[i];
        }
fstream file2("names.txt");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
         file >> product_names[i];
        }
```

Here is the final code for the entire program, comments on possible improvements are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float sum[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
float product_prices[101];
int code;
float total;
char waiter_name[9][15];
float price;
int wc;
cout <<"How many waiters are there? \n";
int w; // Maximum 9 waiters
cin >> w;
for (int i=1; i<=w; ++i)
    {cin >>waiter_name[i];}

string a;
char product_names[101][15];
fstream file("prices.txt");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
         file >> product_prices[i];
        }
fstream file2("names.txt");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
         file >> product_names[i];
        }
ST:
while (true)
{   cout << "Please give product code or type -1 when you're done. \n";
    cin >> code;
    if (code==-1) break;
    cout << "Please give the waiter's code. \n";
    cin >> wc;
    price=product_prices[code];
    cout <<"Default price is " << price << " . Type Y/N if you want to make a special price or A to chose another product or waiter\n";
    cin >> a;
    if (a=="Y"||a=="y") { cin >> price; }
    else if (a=="A" || a=="a") {goto ST;}

    sum[wc]+=price;
    cout << waiter_name[wc] <<" : " <<sum[wc] <<"\n";

}
for (int i=1; i<=w; ++i)
{
    cout << waiter_name[i] <<" : " <<sum[i] <<"\n";
    total+= sum[i];
}


return 0;
}
```

also @ArchbishopOfBanterbury I did not expect you to write this entire program just for this. However, i can't understand what the buffer does, i just have one product_prices.txt and a product_names.txt and the product code is the number of the line. As for the untested code, it is far above my level of knowledge, i don't even know how to use map. Thank you nevertheless.

The product prices are placed in the file, one beneath the other. The names are stored in this manner too. e.g the name of the first product is in the first line of product_names.txt and it's price at the first line of product_prices.txt .

Comment: You parse the file before asking the user for input. Save all prices in a `std::vector`.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad, could you please post some code you attempted and where you're stuck in particular?

Comment: The formatting is terrible. And why do you have a label with no `goto`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i do have a goto on line 36, also what's wrong with the formatting? Do i have to leave more empty lines?

Comment: Maybe it looks different to you but here the indentation is all over the place. Couldn't see the `goto` because of that :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you can, please edit my post, reformatting the code, you probably know better.

Comment: @f9t0: You can do it yourself! Just apply common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code provides the rough outline of a way to do this where each line of the input file is saved to a `std::map` where the key of the map corresponds to the line of the input file and the value is the price of this line of the file. Then prices associated with a line of the file can quickly be accessed using the `find` method of `std::map` which returns an iterator to the position searched for in the map.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main(void) {

    std::map<unsigned int, double> line_price_map;

    // give file name (and absolute path if not in current directory) here
    const char* file_path = "";
    std::ifstream file(file_path);

    std::string buffer = "";
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (getline(file, buffer)) {
         // convert std::string buffer to a double
         double price = atof(buffer.c_str());
         line_price_map.insert(std::make_pair(++count, price));
    }

    // search for a specific line:
    double search_price = line_price_map.find(5)->second;
}
```

This code isn't complete of course, and will require changing for your exact requirements.

As for storing the product name and product code, I would have text file containing these data in the following format:

```
product_code    product_name    product_price
...             ...             ...
```

Such that you can read the contents in line-by-line using `getline` as before, parse the input to get the code of the product, it's name and price then store these values in a `std::map` structure such as this:

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::pair<std::string, double>> product_map;
```

where the key of type `unsigned int` represents the product_code (could also be a `std::string`) and the `std::pair<std::string, double>` (the value of the map associated with the key) gives the product_name (as the `std::string`) and the product price (as the `double`).

Here's some (untested) code I just wrote to make it clearer:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

/**
 * Parses std::string _buffer line input, assigning correct data
 * to code, name and price params.
 */
void parse_input(unsigned int& _prod_code, std::string& _prod_name, 
    double& _prod_price, const std::string& _buffer) {
    size_t count1 = 0;
    // find first tab character
    while (_buffer.at(count1) != '\t') {
        ++count1;
    }
    // set product code to substring of _buffer from beginning
    // to first tab, converted to integral type
    _prod_code = atoi(_buffer.substr(0, count1).c_str());
    size_t count2 = count1 + 1;
    // find second tab character
    while (_buffer.at(count2) != '\t') {
        ++count2;
    }
    // set product code to substring of _buffer from end of first tab
    // to next tab occurrence
    _prod_name = _buffer.substr(count1 + 1, count2);
    size_t count3 = count2 + 1;
    while (_buffer.at(count3) != '\t') {
        ++count3;
    }
    // set product price to last entry of tabbed columns of input
    _prod_price = atof(_buffer.substr(count2 + 1, count3).c_str());
}

int main(void) {
    std::map<unsigned int, std::pair<std::string, double>> product_map;

    const char* pfile_path = "product_data.txt";
    std::ifstream product_file(pfile_path);

    std::string buffer = "";
    // get file contents line by line
    while (getline(product_file, buffer)) {
        unsigned int product_code;
        std::string product_name;
        double product_price;
        // call parse_input with product data vars and buffer
        parse_input(product_code, produce_name, product_price, buffer);
        // insert data to product_map
        product_map.insert(std::make_pair(product_code,
                           std::make_pair(product_name, product_price)));
    }
}
```

This uses a pretty crude parsing function but it should work fairly well - assuming product data is tab delimited in the file as shown above.